# Array with mixed data-types in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Given the following code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    dynamic[] arr = { 5, "test2", "test3"};
    foreach (var i in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

it prints the following:

```
Int32
String
String
```

I can't understand how can an array has elements of different types. From a C background, array elements should be having the same type and each element should take the same amount of RAM. Because in C, something like `arr[i]` would be equivalent to `*(arr + i)` and the pointer `arr` would move `i * sizeof(arr data type)` steps.

Comment: C# arrays are on a much higher level of abstraction than C arrays, so don't be surprised.

Comment: You are defining array as `dyanmic` which indicates it can hold any `object`. If you want to have specific datatype array then define as `int[] arr = {5, 6}`. With the later definition, if you try to add `string` value then you will get the compilation error.

Comment: [dynamic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types)

Comment: As for your questions about pointer navigation, the array you declared is saved on the stack with references to the items in the array so, in reality, you're asking 'what's the type of an object at index i'. consider it like using void pointers.

Comment: I know that it holds `object`, but not all `object`s have the same size. so, when I access arr[0] it goes to the start of the array in the ram, but how does it know how many bytes to read then ?

Comment: @Sweeper - That explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Vnvizitiu, Can you add a more detailed explanation ? Indeed, the specific answer I want is about how it really works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dynamic[] arr = { 5, "test2", "test3"};
```

results in `object[]` (you can see if you call `arr.GetType()`).

The array contains objects of the same type; in this case the type is `object`.

---

## Boxing and unboxing

The elements in your array are boxed. This passage is from [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object instance and stores it on the managed heap.

An `object[]` array, even for value types, does not contain the objects themselves; it contains references to them (btw. `string` [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-string-type) a reference type in C#).

Again, this is from [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#boxing).

[image]

---

## `dynamic` in `C#`

I think the first sentence from [Using type dynamic (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) could clarify how dynamic works in C#.

> C# 4 introduces a new type, `dynamic`. The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking.

The quote from [Built-in reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types) may even be better.

> The dynamic type indicates that use of the variable and references to its members bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time. (...)
>
> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances.

Comment: My question is more about the array, not `dynamic`. I'm wondering how it knows the size of each specific element. In C, when all array elements of the same size, the indexing works as I stated in my question. but in case of `dynamic` or `object` array, this can't be the case.

Comment: Just saw the answer edit now, since this is the most complete answer. I've marked it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in C#, all classes inherit from `Object`.

An `Object[]` array is actually an array containing pointers to the actual objects, so the size is always the same.

The memory would look like this :

[image]

A `dynamic[]` array will be casted to `Object[]`, therefore accepting any data type in there.

About structure, which don't inherit from `Object`, the run-time uses a trick called [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) to put the structure inside an object, therefore allowing the structure item to enter the array.

Comment: Does that mean that, array elements are just lying randomly in the ram, but a reference (pointer) to each element is what forms the real array ?

Comment: @Youssef13 yep, the equivalent in C would be an array of pointers. Except that the runtime knows which type is hidden behind each object

Answer (score 0):

A `dynamic` type will be stored as an object but at run time the compiler will load many more bytes to make sense of what to do with the `dynamic` type. In order to do that, a lot more memory will be used to figure that out. Think of `dynamic` as a fancy object.